# My code starts extremely quick but slows down tremendously

Tags: c#, sql, parallel-processing

My code below works perfectly and I don't get any exceptions at all. It will run extremely quick for approximately 100 seconds and then it slows to a crawl. I followed someone's advice on a related question and paused my program in Vs around 10 times when it slows down and it keeps hitting the same line which I will mark below.

My only theory is that I'm using a `parallel foreach` loop and I believe it acts like a multi threaded application where it continues the code before it finishes and it is hitting the code that comes after the loop which is where it keeps slowing down.

Just so you understand my code below, both the table and adapter are part of a strongly typed sql dataset that I'm accessing in my code. I don't understand how the speed issue is related to the parallel foreach loop though...

```
public static void startDownload()
    {
                List<string> markets = new List<string>() { "amex", "global", "nasdaq", "nyse" };

                Parallel.ForEach(markets, market =>
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> symbolList = Helper.getStockSymbols(market);
                    var historicalGroups = symbolList.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                      .GroupBy(x => x.i / 100)
                      .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.x).ToArray());
                    historicalGroups.AsParallel().ForAll(g => Downloads.getHistoricalStockData(g, market));
                });
            }

            // wait 24 hours before you do this again
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(24)).Wait();
    }

public static List<string> getStockSymbols(string market)
    {
        List<string> symbolList = new List<string>();

            using (SymbolsDataTable symbolTable = new SymbolsDataTable())
            using (SymbolsTableAdapter symbolAdapter = new SymbolsTableAdapter())
            {
                symbolAdapter.FillByActiveSymbols(symbolTable, market);

                var query = from c in symbolTable
                            select c.Symbol;

                return query.AsParallel().ToList();
            }
    }

public static void getHistoricalStockData(string[] symbols, string market)
    {
        // download data for list of symbols and then upload to db tables
        Uri uri;
        string url;
        List<StockData> results = new List<StockData>();
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
        DailyAmexDataDataTable tempTable = new DailyAmexDataDataTable();

        Parallel.ForEach(symbols, async symbol =>
            {
                    url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + symbol + "&a=00&b=1&c=1900&d=" + (DateTime.Now.Month - 1) + "&e=" + DateTime.Now.Day + "&f=" + DateTime.Now.Year + "&g=d&ignore=.csv";
                    uri = new Uri(url);
                    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                    webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                    webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
                    webRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 24;
                    webRequest.Timeout = 10000;
                    webRequest.Headers.Add("UserAgent", "Pentia; MSI");

                    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
                    watch.Start();
                    WebResponse webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
                    watch.Stop();
                    Debug.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

                    using (DailyAmexDataDataTable table = new DailyAmexDataDataTable())
                    using (DailyAmexDataTableAdapter adapter = new DailyAmexDataTableAdapter())
                    using (Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        adapter.Adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 1000;
                                adapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
                        try
                        {
                             adapter.FillBySymbol(table, symbol);
                        }

                        bool breakLoop = false;
                        while (breakLoop == false && reader.EndOfStream == false)
                        {
                            Object lockDate = new Object();

                            lock (lockDate)
                            {
                                string[] lineArray;
                                string line;
                                line = reader.ReadLine();
                                lineArray = line.Split(',');
                                DateTime testDate = new DateTime();
                                bool isDate = DateTime.TryParse(lineArray[0], out testDate);
                                decimal open = 0, high = 0, low = 0, close = 0, adjClose = 0;
                                DateTime date = new DateTime();
                                Int64 volume = 0;

                                // if it isn't the very first line
                                if (isDate)
                                {
                                    // set the data for each array here
                                    DateTime.TryParse(lineArray[0], out date);
                                    Decimal.TryParse(lineArray[1], out open);
                                    Decimal.TryParse(lineArray[2], out high);
                                    Decimal.TryParse(lineArray[3], out low);
                                    Decimal.TryParse(lineArray[4], out close);
                                    Int64.TryParse(lineArray[5], out volume);
                                    Decimal.TryParse(lineArray[6], out adjClose);

                                    var amexQuery = from c in table
                                                            where c.Date == date
                                                            select new StockData { Close = c.AdjustedClose };

                                    results = amexQuery.AsParallel().ToList();

                                    if (results != null)
                                    {
                                        breakLoop = true;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        adapter.Insert(symbol, open, high, low, close, volume, adjClose, date);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        tempTable = (DailyAmexDataDataTable)table.GetChanges();

                        if (tempTable != null)
                        {
                            adapter.Update(tempTable);
                            tempTable.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67380/discussion-on-question-by-user3610374-my-code-starts-extremely-quick-but-slows-d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeat after me "NEVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER call `Task.Wait()`".

Okay, I've got that out of the way.

Each call to `Task.Wait()` causes a thread to sleep. In this case you are causing all your thread pool threads to sleep for 24 hours each. Which is completely utterly insane. The result is that TPL doesn't have any Threads left to run code on.

The CORRECT way to do this, would be to either use a scheduler, OR use `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(24))` instead.

Comment: *NEVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER call Task.Wait()*

Comment: NEVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER call Task.Wait()

Comment: I changed it to this code and it seems to run a bit better but now the program is crashing and I'm getting a IndexOutOfRangeException and I have try catch blocks in every bit of code but it crashes anyway. I'm really confused by this

Comment: Most likely you have a bug in your CSV reader code. Consider using a library like CSV Helper.

Comment: Is there a way to see where the bug is in my code first? I'm trying to use this opportunity to learn and not repeat this mistake in the future. I tried pausing but it doesn't show the exception and I did some experimenting and for some reason the main program method that calls the startdownload method runs a while (true) { startdownload() } and this is supposed to stay on but only run every 24 hours. I deleted this while loop and I noticed that was causing my program to crash. If I put the while loop back in, the program seems to work like before. I have no idea how to explain or fix this